# Where can I get Bootstrap 3.0 code and documentation?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

It seems the code and the documenation that used to be on http://rc.getbootstrap.com/ has disappeared.
I used to be able to access:

- http://rc.getbootstrap.com/components/
- http://rc.getbootstrap.com/css.
- ...

But now these pages can't be accessed anymore.

Where is it ? or does somebody know when it will boostrap 3.0 be released officially on a stable version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 documentation is now the default: http://getbootstrap.com/

For legacy bootstrap 2.3.2 docs: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

nJoy!

Comment: The doc for v3.0.0 is still up at http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.0/docs/components/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the offline documentation for the current version at: https://github.com/AAlakkad/Bootstrap-3-Offline-Docs

Comment: @rayryeng The question asked for the link to the documentation :)

Comment: @matiash the answer provided a link, and it contains documentation, i don't see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the documentation and code here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/3.0.0-wip

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks a lot. Do you know if Twitter has said when (even approwimately) will the 3.0 version be released ? huge fan here

Comment: I don't know anything specific, but you can watch the progress here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6342